# C: problem using argv: invalid initializer

Tags: c, argv

does anyone know why it throws following error when trying to run:

```
decrypt.c: In function 'main':
decrypt.c:14:30: error: invalid initializer
   14 |         char currentWord[] = argv[count];
      |
```

It occurs in line 14. I want to pass every command line parameter into the char[] current word, but somehow it doesn't work.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    for (int count = 1; count <= argc; count++) {

        char tmp1;
        char tmp2;
        int countCurrent = 0;

        char currentWord[] = argv[count];

        int wordLength = strlen(currentWord);
        int amountOfLetters = wordLength/2;

        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfLetters; i++){

            tmp1 = currentWord[countCurrent];
            ++countCurrent;
            printf("Das ist der %i. Wert: %c\n",countCurrent, tmp1);

            tmp2 = currentWord[countCurrent];
            ++countCurrent;
            printf("Das ist der %i. Wert: %c\n",countCurrent, tmp2);
        }

        countCurrent = 0;
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help :)

Best Enno

Comment: `<=` when comparing with a size in a loop is almost always wrong. If `argc` is e.g. `5`, then the last index you should use for `count` is `4`, not `5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't initialize an array this way.

You need to:

```
char currentWord[strlen(argv[count]) + 1];
strcpy(currentWord, argv[count]);
```

Indexes are from zero in C language

```
for (int count = 0; count < argc; count++)
```

Comment: thanks, works now :)!